# I need to find the function argument has a return type or not using Pycparser.How will I do that?

Tags: python, function, abstract-syntax-tree, pycparser

My code is:-

```
class FuncDefVisitor(c_ast.NodeVisitor):

    def visit_FuncDef(self, node):
    
    node.body.show()

    node.decl.type.args.show()

    print('%s at %s' % (node.decl.name, node.decl.coord))
```

I am unable to understand how to find if the function argument has a return type and if it has a return type I have to generate an error message . How can I do it using the PYCPARSER??

Comment: Not sure what you mean by the "function argument" - the function arguments are "self" and "node", so not sure what it would mean for them to have a return value. Do you mean you want to see if there's an explicit `return` statement anywhere inside the function body? Or that you want to look for type annotation info?

Comment: Thats easy, every function has a return value

Comment: I need to parse a code using pycparser and find out if the function argument is returned or not.If it is returned then i need to give an error message  Like suppose:-  if i have a function as int fn_a(int a) and if there is something like "return a" in the code then error will be printed